# Reparameterizing quaternion in terms of angle

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, quaternions

Why is the red part true?

[image: https://i.snipboard.io/PTOhuN.jpg]

From: http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-17-winter/Papers/quaternion.pdf

Comment: $\cos\theta$ is a continous and monotonous function on $[0,\pi]$. Therefore it takes any value from $-1$ to $1$ exactly once on this interval.

Comment: @user but what about the first circled part?

Comment: It follows that $\cos^2\theta$ is also continous function which takes on any value from $0$ to $1$, so that the equation $\cos^2\theta=q_0^2$ has a solution.

Comment: The range of $\cos^2\theta$ is $[0,1]$ which includes $q_0^2$. Choosing $\theta$ to make $\cos^2\theta=q_0^2$, it immediately implies $\sin^2\theta=\|{\bf q}\|^2$ too. Indeed, there are two supplementary solutions for $\theta$, yielding opposite values for $\cos\theta$, so you can pick the right one to make $\cos\theta=q_0$ and $\sin\theta=\|{\bf q}\|$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** Notice $\sin ^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. What does $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ lead to? Consider its graph $(x=\cos \theta, y=\sin \theta )$ on the plane, with $x^2+y^2=1$, which is exactly an upper semicircle.

Comment: Yes, I understand this identity. But just because a+b=c and d+e=c does not mean a=d and b=e

Comment: You can't do that. I just wrote out in variables why you can't substitute the terms in a sum.

Comment: Notice here $a,b,d,e$ are NOT constants, but variables. We only need a one-to-one correspondence, then the 2 **representations** are equivalent. We don't have any information loss.

Comment: But in this case, d and e are not independent free variables. They are related by theta. For example, if q_0 = .1 and ||q||^2 = .9... I see. So for any values of q_0 and ||q||^2, the vector made by those two components will always lie on the unit circle, and can thus always be represented by an angle

Comment: in this case $a$ and $b$ are also not independent free variables. Once you choose one $q_0$, then $\|q\|$ is uniquely determined. Just as we choose one $\cos \theta$ and then $\sin \theta$ is uniquely determined.